# Elastic search: hour_minute_second mapping returns empty data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

Below mapping i have created for search field

```
PUT /sample/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "webDateTime1": {
      "type":   "date",
      "format": "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss||dd-MM-yyyy||hour_minute_second"
    }
  }
}
```

If i search based on "04-04-2019 20:17:18" getting proper data
if i search based on "04-04-2019" getting proper data
if i search based on "20:17:18" don't know always getting empty result.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ingest some sample docs:

```json
POST sample/_doc/1
{"webDateTime1":"04-04-2019 20:17:18"}

POST sample/_doc/2
{"webDateTime1":"04-04-2019"}

POST sample/_doc/3
{"webDateTime1":"20:17:18"}
```

and then aggregate on the date field,

```json
GET sample/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "dt_values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "webDateTime1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you'll see how the values are *actually* indexed:

```json
...
"buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 73038000,
          "key_as_string" : "01-01-1970 20:17:18",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 1554336000000,
          "key_as_string" : "04-04-2019 00:00:00",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 1554409038000,
          "key_as_string" : "04-04-2019 20:17:18",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
...
```

That's the reason your query for `20:17:18` is causing you a headache.

Now, you'd typically wanna use the `range` query like so:

```json
GET sample/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "webDateTime1": {
        "gte": "20:17:18",
        "lte": "20:17:18",
        "format": "HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the `format` parameter. But again, if you don't provide a `date` in your `datetime` field, it turns out it's going to take the unix epoch as the date.

Comment: i can see below result in my aggregations
"aggregations" : {
    "dt_values" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1554322638000,
          "key_as_string" : "03-04-2019 20:17:18",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : 1554409038000,
          "key_as_string" : "04-04-2019 20:17:18",
          "doc_count" : 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }

while searching search query it is giving me empty result.

Comment: That's because all 4 of your documents include datetimes, not dates. Use this instead: `{"query":{"range":{"webDateTime1":{"gte":"03-04-2019 20:17:18","lte":"04-04-2019 20:17:18","format":"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"}}}}`