# Filter by time with any date

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to filter documents only by time. For example, if I provide timestamps like: `7:00:00` and `15:00:00` by GMT, they should return dates like `15 Dec 2020`, `30 April 1340` and so on.

This query obviously does not work (I use node.js client), because it returns any date between 1000 year and 3000 year:

```
searchResult = await esClient.transport.request({
  method: 'GET',
  path: 'events/_search',
  body: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: {
           range: {
             date: {
               gte: '1000-07-15T07:00:00Z',
               lte: '3000-07-15T15:00:00Z'
             }
           }
         }
      }
    },
  }
});
```

As well as this query, because, according to [this docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#missing-date-components), my provided timestamps (`7:00:00` and `15:00:00`) are converted into dates with default values:

```
searchResult = await esClient.transport.request({
  method: 'GET',
  path: 'events/_search',
  body: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: {
           range: {
             date: {
               'gte': '7:00:00',
               'lte': '15:00:00',
                format: 'HH:mm:ss'
             }
           }
         }
      }
    },
  }
});
```

How can I filter only by time, but not days, months, years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to the "Missing date components" part from the docs -- if there's no `YYYY-MM-DD`, [it'll default to `1970-01-01`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61013108/8160318).

What's usually done when you want to query date-less time ranges is that you save the elapsed time since midnight of that day in a purely numerical value. Depending on the precision needs of the use case it could be

- the hour (as in the [business opening hours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7118625/8160318) problem, for example)
- seconds since midnight
- etc.

That way you're left with a simple numerical `range` query. The incoming ranges would then of course need to be provided in a format compliant with the way you're storing the time values.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it by storing two separate fields: date `strict_date` and time `strict_hour_minute_second`:

```
searchResult = await esClient.transport.request({
  method: 'GET',
  path: 'events/_search',
  body: {
    query: {
        range: {
          time: {
            gte: '14:20:00',
            lte: '14:30:00'
          }
        }
      }
  }
});
```